# Best ODM solution on PHP that support versioning

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm, document-versioning

We are planning the develop of a CMS based in PHP. We are evaluating the possibility to use some open source ODM framework. We are a special interest in document versioning features.

PHPCR
We have strong expertise in Doctrine and so one good candidate can be PHPCR supported by Doctrine plugin. But to have versioning support we must use Apache Jackrabbit.

PHP-MONGO
Alternative can be using PHP-MONGO, a PHP ODM based on MongoDB that support document versioning.

We are looking for opinions and pro/contro over this solutions or other proposal of PHP based ODM that support Versioning?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Giving recommendations and opinions are both considered off-topic, for valid reasons. We don't know your full end-to-end requirements either, so any opinions which are given will necessarily be done without complete knowledge of the situation. I doubt you want to put your entire spec on here, and potential answers are merely opinions (even if formed from a lot of experience) or even potentially commercially-motivated

Comment: The question would be really specific to the document versioning  feature. Would not be "what ODM is better?" but in PHP what ODM implementation better support document versioning and in what measure, and if anyone tested it in a real project.

Comment: that's still a recommendation, in effect, just narrowed down to a smaller feature set. And it's also something you are likely to be able to determine by looking at product documentation. This site answers detailed coding questions, primarily. You might do better on a site which is interested in software architecture or database design.